# Transitive/Intransitive Verbs in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, transitivity

I want to know which  object (verbal transitivity)  is coming first

> I gave **her** / **the ball**
>                       Or
>   I gave **the ball** / **to her**
>
> I denied **A piece of cake** / **to her**
>                        Or
>   I denied **her** / **a piece of cake**

I have a serious doubt about using 2 objects with only a verb. I want to know which object is coming first.

For example: The verb **to give**; I want to know if I should say "He gave me the ball" or "He gave the ball to me" . I want to know if the object pronouns comes first or not

Or I can say these 2 forms,  both being grammatically  correct?

Comment: Which do you think is correct?  Why do you think so?  What does your textbook say?  Without more detail this question will likely be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by *object* and by *coming first*? (And why would there be confusion?)

Comment: What I mean by object is the "direct/indirect" object  (for transitive verbs). I want to know which one I should  use first (I should say "He toss me the ball" or "He toss the ball to me"?) . I thought saying the second option would be wrong.